# The cycle does not run automatically

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android. My program simulates the operation of traffic lights and displays the appropriate color depending on the number of seconds have passed. By clicking on the `buttonRandom` from 0 to 6 seconds displays a green background, from 6 to 7 seconds displays a yellow background, and from 7 to 9 seconds is displayed red background.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonRed:
            mTextView.setText(R.string.buttonRed);
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
            break;
        case R.id.buttonYellow:
            mTextView.setText(R.string.buttonYellow);
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorYellow));
            break;
        case R.id.buttonRandom:
            int count = 0;
            while (count <= 10) {
                Date date = new Date();
                int sec = date.getSeconds();
                if (sec % 10 >= 0 && sec % 10 < 6) {
                    mTextView.setText(R.string.buttonGreen);
                    mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
                    count++;
                }
                else if (sec % 10 >= 6 && sec % 10 < 7) {
                    mTextView.setText(R.string.buttonYellow);
                    mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorYellow));
                    count++;
                }
                else if (sec % 10 >= 7 && sec % 10 < 9) {
                    mTextView.setText(R.string.buttonRed);
                    mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
                    count++;
                }
            }
    }
```

However, this code does not change the background on their own, it is necessary each time to press the button. How to make sure that when you press one time, the background changes automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, this code does not change the background on their own, it is necessary each time to press the button.

That's because your while loop runs so fast, it is already done with 10 loops before a second has passed. You want to use a handler or something here to do the check every second

```
int sec = 0;
case R.id.buttonRandom:
    final Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (sec % 10 >= 0 && sec % 10 < 6) {
                mTextView.setText(R.string.buttonGreen);
                mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
            } else if (sec % 10 >= 6 && sec % 10 < 7) {
                mTextView.setText(R.string.buttonYellow);
                mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorYellow));
            } else if (sec % 10 >= 7 && sec % 10 < 9) {
                mTextView.setText(R.string.buttonRed);
                mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
            }

            sec++;
            if (sec < 11) {
                h.postDelayed(this);
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you did is one time only action when the button is clicked, it does not listen to time changes.

[Here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-timer-example/) you have a tutorial on working with timers. Go through it and it will teach you how to work with timer, after that, just adjust it to your needs (e.g. change color instead of text).

Answer (score 0):

```
private long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
private long updatedTime = 0L;
private long startTime = 0L;
//thread for 5 sec
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeInMilliseconds;

        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        secs = secs % 60;

        if (secs % 10 >= 0 && secs % 10 < 6) {
            mTextView.setText(R.string.buttonGreen);
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
            count++;
        } else if (sec % 10 >= 6 && sec % 10 < 7) {

            mTextView.setText(R.string.buttonYellow);
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorYellow));
            count++;

        }


    else if(sec%10>=7&&sec%10<9)

    {
        mTextView.setText(R.string.buttonRed);
        mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
        count++;
    }
}
};
```

try this on button clcik